# Html helpers are running AFTER view engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I'm using ASP.Net MVC 3 with the Razor engine.

I have an html helper that will be returning @Url.Action.  The problem I'm running into is that the @Url.Action is not getting converted into a proper url.  Instead the @Url.Action gets returned as part of the html.

It looks like the razor engine runs and then the html helpers run after the fact?  That seems kind of backwards to me.  Is there anything I can change so that my helper will run first?

Here is an example:

```
public static HtmlString Test(this HtmlHelper helper)
{ 
    return new HtmlString("@Url.Action('Logoff', 'Login'");
}
```

In my _Layout.cshtml I have this..

```
@Html.Test()
```

And the html will show up as @Url.Action('Logoff', 'Login')

Comment: **is not getting converted into a proper url**. What exactly does it get converted to ? Encoded string ?

Comment: @Url.Action gets returned as part of the html.

Comment: Can you post some code from your helper, and also how you call it from the view ?

Comment: Obviously I made my sample too simple.  I'm actually trying to return a list of URLs.  Not just a single one.  What I'm really going for at the end of the day are dynamic menus based off a SiteMap file I have already with a bit of role checking in the mix.

Comment: So wait -- back to my original point.  It appears that HtmlHelpers CANNOT return Razor code.  Instead they have to do the work themselves to get the real html.  Is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending `UrlHelper` seems more appropriate and natural when dealing with urls:

```
public static string Test(this UrlHelper helper)
{
    return helper.Action("Logoff", "Login");
}
```

And in your view:

```
@Url.Test()
```

Comment: We're actually building a menu.  I just gave a short example.

Comment: @ShaneC, I don't quite understand what you want in fact. You want to end up with `/Login/Logoff` or `@Url.Action('Logoff', 'Login')` in the final generated HTML that is sent to the browser?

Comment: I want to see /Login/Logoff but it's more like <li><a href='/Login/Logoff'/>Log off</a><li> as in I'm NOT just trying to return a URL.  I'm trying to create a menu which will have a bunch of urls embedded inside of it.

Comment: @ShaneC, great, then my answer should point you to the right direction. If you want anchors then extend the `HtmlHelper` and return an `helper.ActionLink`.

Comment: See my update to my comment.  I want a large string.  Not just a single URL.

Comment: @ShaneC, then simply: `public static string Test(this HtmlHelper helper) { return helper.ActionLink("Log off", "Logoff", "Login"); }` and in your layout: `@Html.Test()`.

Comment: Thanks!  I still think it's odd that we can't return Razor code from an HtmlHelper and have it parsed by the view engine.

Answer (score 0):

It is returning a string because you have quotes around Url.Action - remove the quotes and the @ and it should get evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

You have quoted your `url.action` command, and this has converted it to a literal string.

Also the use of the `@` is the razor syntax, and that will not work in the model/controller files

Use

```
public static HtmlString Test(this HtmlHelper helper)
{ 
    return new HtmlString( helper.Action('Logoff', 'Login') );
}
```

Comment: But we're returning code that is going to be injected into a Razor view.  So even then we don't need the Razor's @?

Comment: @Shane, you will need the `@` syntax in the *view* code of `@html.Test()`. Have a look at http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx to see what the @ replaces. It is just a symbol to denote that code follows. In your controller and models you are always in code mode..

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice you were using the actual helper to do the generation.  That seems like the right direction.